# Link to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, textarea

I want to to create a link that takes the user to the textarea and allows them to start typing in it instantly. This is my textarea:

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>
```

Currently, I just link to it by:

```
<a href="#commentnow">Post a comment</a>
```

But this only takes them to the area of which the textarea is, not inside it so that they can start type. In order to do that, they will obviously need to click on it. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWQbZ/) with my current setup.

I would imagine that there are various solutions to this. I would however request a solution that is centred on compatibility (works on all browsers and particularly phone browsers).

Comment: Pseudocode: `a.onclick = fn(){ textarea.focus(); }`

Comment: Please post an answer with a working fiddle and kindly make a note of compatibility.

Comment: You just posted the original fiddle :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `.focus()` method along with `window.location.hash`.

```
<a href="#comment" onclick="window.location.hash = 'comment'; document.getElementById('comment').focus(); return false;">click</a>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>
```

Use `return false` or `preventDefault()` for this to work everywhere. Chrome/stock browser on android doesn't require this. Firefox mobile does.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeFbU/) for you to test with. Here's another example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeFbU/3/) where the submit is visible while typing.

Comment: It's just a link and getElementById is supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not function in touch screens. I have tested it on the Firefox browser on Android so far.

Comment: Works like a charm on phones, however one final issue remains on Firefox (and potentially on other browsers). On FF, go to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KeFbU/2/ and then click on the link. You will see that the screen goes down to the textarea but doesn't display the submit until you manually scroll down. Is there any way to make the screen go down a bit further? I noticed that it worked fine in Safari though. Can you solve this finally puzzle Ryan?

Comment: Sure, updated my post. Jumps to the box before focusing it so the submit is visible

Comment: @ryan excellent, can you please update your whole answer with the new code and I will accept it as correct (so that other people do not need to visit the fiddle to get it).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21866/discussion-between-ryan-and-gary-woods)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use JavaScript for this, when normal HTML elements can be used; with that in mind just use a `label` element, instead of an `a`, since your requirements are precisely met by the `label` element:

```
<label for="commentnow">Post a comment</label>
<textarea id="commentnow" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uWQbZ/2/).

The `for` attribute of the `label` must be equal to the `id` of the element you want to focus on, and associate with, the `label`.

In response to comment from OP (in comments, below):

> Two questions: How about compatibility and how can I make it a button where the text is clickable (cursor changes when hovering)...?

To address compatibility, the `label` element's been around since HTML 4.01 and I've not come across a browser that doesn't work with it (including IE 7, I can't remember using it with IE 6 though).

To make it appear like a button, just use CSS (in the same way you'd style an `a` element to appear like a button, for example:

```
label {
    color: #666;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

label:hover,
label:active,
label:focus {
    color: #f90;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uWQbZ/8/), this isn't a particularly beautiful example, but does show that styling possibilities both *exist* and are no different than any other element in that regard.

Comment: I agree that this is the more semantic approach but just to play the devil's advocate how many average users (the end users, not developers) do you think know that this functionality exists.

Comment: @A.V: it doesn't matter where the elements are positioned, the `label` is associated with the `input`/`textarea` element, and will, by default, focus it.

Comment: Two questions: How about compatibility and how can I make it a button where the text is clickable (cursor changes when hovering)...?

Comment: @ryan: just because some people don't know an element, or function of an element, exists is no reason not to use it. I'm not sure I understand your comment, though.

Comment: @DavidThomas : Good one. but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uWQbZ/5/) does not brings textarea to top.. Anyway great..! +1

Comment: Unlike other answers, this seem to work *partly* on touch screens. However there is an issue. Let me explain. Open this URL on a touch screen device like a phone: http://jsfiddle.net/T4MwN/2/ Then click on the Post button. It will go to the textarea and open the visual keyboard. All good so far. However, once you have finished writing in the text area and go out of it, it jumps **back** to where the button was - on my site, it will be at the very top of the page while the textarea is at the very bottom... making this a serious issue as the Submit button is underneath the textarea :) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simple try this using jQuery:

```
<a class="link" href="#">Post a comment</a>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea

$(".link").click(function(){
    $("#comment").focus();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: How is compatibility for this solution?